Onvif: Creating new Video Encoder and Video Source Configuration
Maybe I just didn't find it in the documentation, but I couldn't find a way to create a new Video Encoder and Video Source Configuration.
My camera has 2 VideoSources (1 RGB and 1 Thermal Camera), 2 Video Source Configurations and 4 Video Encoder Configurations. As I'm trying to integrate onvif cameras from various companies I thought that creating a new profile/s with my own source config and encoder config would make sense, but I don't know how.
In the Onvif protocol I can only add an video source config and encoder config to a profile and change existing configurations, but it seems I can't create new configs. Does anyone know: are these configs something which is given by the camera producer and can only be adapted? Is this because of hardware restrictions? Or did I just miss something in the onvif docs?
Thank you very much in advance
